# How to setup crontab to remove the php session files

Tags: 14.04, server, php, php7

I want to remove the PHP7.1 session file frequently, if I don't remove the files the new PHP session is not generating. So I want to set up the cron job to remove the PHP session.

Session files are saving in the path : /var/lib/php/sessions

Help me to set up the cron job. Thanks.

Comment: do you already have a command you use to clean the files? if you type `man crontab` from command line instructions are there. you edit your roots crontab with `sudo crontab -e`

Comment: I don't have any commands to setup the cron. will this work * */30 * * * rm -rf /var/lib/php/sessions/* >>/dev/null ?

Comment: you might want to do  rm -rf /var/lib/php/sessions/* to be sure that directory doesn't get deleted, but other than that, that looks correct

Comment: You may want to remove only old sessions, the above will reset active sessions. Use something like `find /var/lib/php/sessions -type f -cmin +60 -delete` to remove sessions older then 1 hour.